# "Gehen Sie an dem roten Haus vorbei...": warum benutzt man den Dativ?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, wechselpraeposition

EDIT: Es scheint, dass das Problem war, das ich "Bewegung" mit "Richtung" verwechselte.

Im Buch "Präpositionen" von Hueber, gibt es folgendes Beispiel für "an":

> Gehen Sie an dem roten Haus vorbei, gleich daneben ist unser Geschäft.

Wieso steht da "an dem", d.h., der Dativ?  Normaleweise, dachte ich, wenn wir von Bewegung sprechen -- "ich hänge das Bild an die Wand" --, dann wird der Akkusativ benutzt. Ich weiss, dass man im obengenannten Fall nicht direkt zum Haus geht, aber wenn ich hätte wählen müssen, ob wir von Bewegung sprechen oder nicht, dann würde ich sagen --> Akkusativ.  Braucht es eine *annähernde* Bewegung zu sein, infolgedessen haben wir hier, mit "vorbei", das nicht?

Eine zusätzliche Frage, wenn ich fragen darf: wieso benutzt man "an dem" im zitierten Text, statt "am"?  Ich dachte, wenn man die Möglichkeit hat, Präposition und Artikel zu verbinden, dann macht man das.

Comment: "wenn wir von Bewegung sprechen, dann wird der Akkusativ benutzt" - das ist schlicht falsch, dieser Irrum hält sich aber hartnäckig. Der Akkusativ wird benutzt, wenn die *Richtung* beschrieben wird. Es muss auch keine Bewegung im Spiel sein, z.B. in "ich schaue auf das Haus".

Comment: Ich habe es soeben oben notiert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Frage kommt daher, dass die Regel zur den Wechselpräpositionen nicht richtig formuliert ist. Die Wechselpräpositionen bezeichnen mit Dativ einen Ort, mit Akkusativ einen Weg, der an diesem Ort endet, bzw. eine Richtung dorthin. Auch "an" ist eine von diesen Präpositionen: "an der Wand" (Ort, wo etwas ist; Dativ), "ein Ei an die Wand werfen" (Akkusativ; das Ei endet an der Wand). Mit Bewegung hat es aber nicht unbedingt zu tun ("Er schaut an die Wand").

Der Ausdruck "an dem Haus vorbei gehen" ist ein anderer Fall. Ich denke, dass es keine Zirkumposition ist, sondern eine Konstruktion, deren Kern das Adverb "vorbei" ist, "am Haus" wäre dann eine nähere Bestimmung dazu. Man kann auch sagen: "geh *dort vorbei*" oder nur "geh vorbei" (wenn der Orientierungspunkt klar ist). Hier ist "vorbei" also ein Richtungsadverb und keine Präposition. Zu diesem liefert dann "am Haus" den Bezugspunkt, an dem der mittlere Teil eines Weges lokalisiert wird, es ist kein Bewegungsziel. "Vorbei gehen" heißt immer auch, dass man weiter geht.

Die Formen "an dem" oder "am" können hier beide benutzt werden, aber ich würde intuitiv hier "an dem" bevorzugen; weiß nicht genau, warum.

Answer (score 2):

Die Regel "Akkusativ für Richtungen, Dativ für Orte" gilt nur für diejenigen Präpositionen, die beides ausdrücken können, wie "in", "auf" oder auch "an".

Hier wird aber die Zirkumposition "an X vorbei" verwendet, die *nur* Richtungen ausdrücken kann, ebenso wie z.B. auch "an X entlang". Diese Konstruktion nimmt immer den Dativ, obwohl sie von Richtungen handelt. Die Faustregel gilt also weniger umfassend, als man sich wünschen würde.

Comment: Warum unbedingt Zirkumposition? Warum nicht Ort + *vorbei*, z.B. *hier vorbei*? Dann wäre der Dativ erwartet. Was macht man mit *gehen Sie vorbei am Haus* oder vielleicht auch *gehen Sie an unserem Café nicht vorbei*?

Comment: "Hier wird aber die Zirkumposition "an X vorbei" verwendet, die nur Richtungen ausdrücken kann, ebenso wie z.B. auch "an X entlang". Diese Konstruktion nimmt immer den Dativ, obwohl sie von Richtungen handelt." --> Welche Konstruktion nimmt immer den Dativ?  "an X vorbei"?  Oder "die Zirkumposition"?