# Warum benutzt man den Dativ mit "willkommen heißen in"?

Tags: grammatical-case

Ich habe seit kurzem eine Frage über den Dativ und den Akkusativ gestellt.  [Bei einer Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/75531/41028) hieß es "Die Wechselpräpositionen bezeichnen mit Dativ einen Ort, mit Akkusativ einen Weg, der an diesem Ort endet, bzw. eine Richtung dorthin."

Also verstehe ich nicht ganz, warum hier man den Dativ gebraucht (dieser Satz kommt vom [DWDS-Korpus](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=willkommen%20hei%C3%9Fen&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10)):

> Mit brüderlicher Umarmung hat Papst Johannes Paul II. den
> Ökumenischen Patriarchen von Konstantinopel, Bartholomaios I., im
> Vatikan willkommen geheißen.

Das heißt, warum sagt man "**im** Vatikan", nicht "**in den** Vatikan" bei "willkommen heißen in"?

Weil wir schon da sind?  Meines Erachtens ist Richtung impliziert. (Offensichtlich stimmt meine Überlegung nicht!)

Comment: Im Englischen und vermutlich in anderen Sprachen sagt man "welcome to ...", das deutsche "Willkommen in ..." hat da eine andere Logik. Die Verwirrung ist verständlich, aber die Frage nach dem Warum ist immer schwer zu beantworten...

Comment: @HalvarF ich habe schon fast Mitleid mit deiner Beschwerde, aber viel wichtiger ist doch: die Frage nach dem Warum ist immer schwer zu formulieren. Das heißt, viele Fragen führen halt zu einer Antwort, “ist halt so”, die eher das “wie jetzt” betrifft (you wot m8?). Das ist bald *zu einfach*. Was du an dieser Frage als schwierig empfindest, kann ich jedoch kaum erahnen, Jedenfalls hat mir die Fragestellung schon weitergeholfen, **the Greek locativized ἔνδοι** (eDiAna, \*endon, 7. Reconstruction, https://www.ediana.gwi.uni-muenchen.de/dictionary.php?lemma=3443#31), vgl. engl. *into*, de. *ins*!

Comment: Übrigens kennt englisch auch “welcome **on** board” ~ de. *willkommen an Deck*. (nicht *auf Deck*?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wenn man jemanden willkommen heißt (oder auch begrüßt), dann steht der Ort fest und beide Leute befinden sich schon an dem Ort; der Gastgeber begrüßt die andere(n) Person(en):

> Ich heiße Dich in meinem Heim willkommen.
> Ich heiße Dich in unsererem Verein willkommen
> Sei mir in meinem trauten Heim herzlich willkommen!

Dagegen bei "hineinbitten" oder "einladen" ist der (zukünftige) Gast noch nicht (ganz) angekommen, und es ist noch eine Richtung impliziert, sodass diese mit Akkusativ gebildet werden:

> Ich lade Dich in mein Heim ein
> Ich bitte Dich in mein Heim hinein.